# How to reference on a different row when you have a joint key in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

my code in MySQL workbench

```
SELECT
id,
user_id,
parent_id,
approved_time,
@new_approved_t:=IF(new_product_type != 'B', approved_time, @new_approved_t))AS new_approved_time
FROM p
```

my data frame look like this after I run the code:

```
id  user_id  parent_id     product_type  approved_time   New_approved_time
30    11            NA       A            8/4/2017         8/4/2017
31    11            30       B            12/1/2017        8/4/2017
54    5             NA       A            5/5/2018         5/5/2018
322   5             54       B            7/22/2018        5/5/2018
21    5             NA       C            8/1/2018         8/1/2018
13    5             NA       C            8/2/2018         8/2/2018
2445  5             NA       C            9/25/2018        9/25/2018
111   44            NA       A            10/4/2018        10/4/2018
287   44            111      B            10/8/2018        10/4/2018
211   33            NA       A            12/5/2018        12/5/2018
277   33            211      B            12/25/2018       12/5/2018
1120  33            NA       C            1/1/2019         1/1/2019
1389  33            211      B            1/11/2019        1/1/2019
```

I would like all my product_type ending in 'B' and it's new_approved_time column to use the corresponding parent_id approved time. The result should look like in below:

```
id  user_id  parent_id     product_type  approved_time   New_approved_time
30    11            NA       A            8/4/2017         8/4/2017
31    11            30       B            12/1/2017        8/4/2017
54    5             NA       A            5/5/2018         5/5/2018
322   5             54       B            7/22/2018        5/5/2018
21    5             NA       C            8/1/2018         8/1/2018
13    5             NA       C            8/2/2018         8/2/2018
2445  5             NA       C            9/25/2018        9/25/2018
111   44            NA       A            10/4/2018        10/4/2018
287   44            111      B            10/8/2018        10/4/2018
211   33            NA       A            12/5/2018        12/5/2018
277   33            211      B            12/25/2018       12/5/2018
1120  33            NA       C            1/1/2019         1/1/2019
1389  33            211      B            1/11/2019        12/5/2018    <-this is where I dont know how to write my code
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you are attempting, but if you're going to use an @/session variable like that, you need an ORDER BY clause to insure the order in which the rows are evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Because the parent (pp) has its own value there needs to be a self join like this. Because of the join criteria `pp.approved_time` will be `NULL` for non-B products.

```
SELECT
p.id,
p.user_id,
p.parent_id,
p.approved_time,
COALESCE(pp.approved_time, p.approved_time) AS new_approved_time
FROM p
LEFT JOIN p AS pp ON p.new_product_type = 'B' AND p.parent_id = pp.id
```

Comment: pp table doesn't exist though

Comment: LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM p) pp ON p.new_product_type = 'B' AND p.parent_id = pp.id  I tried this code, but it's telling me that can't reopen table p

Comment: Corrected - `pp` is a `p`  alias (parent p).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here with another column I didn't include in my example, but basically it's the reverse of parent_id column I listed above which only listed id in product_type A and rest of them is null.

But I got hint from Dan's code on COALESCE() function, thanks Dan.

```
CASE WHEN c.new_product_type IN ('A', 'B') THEN @new_approved_t:=IF(COALESCE(if((a.is_loc=1 AND b.ploc_RID IS NOT NULL), a.id, null)), a.approved_time, @new_approved_t)
          ELSE a.approved_time END AS new_approved_time
```

Comment: danger: user variables means you can only store one state of the parent id and you are very dependent on the order of the items in the table.